# Error en sacar porcentajes en un arreglo C

Tags: c

tengo el siguiente arreglo de los cuales tengo que sacar el porcentaje total que cubre cada posicion

```
int votosPorCandidato [3] = {1847,270,2433,83}
```

Aca les muestra la llamada a la funcion. Candidatos = 4. votosTotales es una variable que tiene la sumatoria de los datos del arreglo anterior. votosPorCandidato es la funcion atenrior. porcentajeVotosPorCandidato es el arreglo tipo float que le paso a la funcion para que se almacenen los porcentajes

```
porcentajeVotos(candidatos,votosTotales,votosPorCandidato,porcentajeVotosPorCandidato);
```

Hice la siguiente funcion para que me saque los porcentajes y los guarde en un arreglo tipo float

```
void porcentajeVotos (int candidatos, int totales, int votos[], float porcentajes[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int copia [3];
    while(i<candidatos)
    {
        copia[i] = votos[i];
        i++;
    }


    int x = 0;
    int dato;
    while(x<candidatos)
    {
        porcentajes[x] = (float)(copia[x] * 100) / (float)totales;
        x++;
    }

}
```

Cuando compilo me muestra mal los porcentajes y me altera datos de el arreglo votosPorCandidato.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La cuestión es simple, los arreglos que  tienes los defines con 3 espacios y deberían de ser con 4, debido a que tienen 4 cantidades dentro del arreglo. Solo modifica ese 3 por 4.
Ejemplo

```
Int arreglo[4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema que aparece es este:

```
int votosPorCandidato [3] = {1847,270,2433,83}
```

Ya que si bien los arrays se leen desde el índice 0 hasta el índice anterior al numero total de índices, a la hora de definirlo hay que hacerlo con su número total de elementos. Así que un array de 4 elementos sera `array[4]` aunque lo recorra desde el `array[0]` hasta el `array[3]`

Este problema lo tienes de nuevo al hacer la copia:

```
int copia [3];
```

Este array sólo puede albergar tres `int`, y no cuatro.

Con esto te debería funcionar.

```
int votosPorCandidato[4] = {1847,270,2433,83};
```

y

```
void porcentajeVotos (int candidatos, int totales, const int votos[], float porcentajes[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int copia [4];
    while(i<candidatos)
    {
        copia[i] = votos[i];
        i++;
    }


    int x = 0;
    int dato;
    while(x<candidatos)
    {
        porcentajes[x] = (float)(copia[x] * 100) / (float)totales;
        x++;
    }

}
```

Dicho lo cual, te hago algunas observaciones:
Dices que el array de votos queda modificado. No hay nada en la función que lo modifique, creo que es más bien una percepción equivocada ya que cuando accedes al último valor tiene cualquier cosa (basura) porque está fuera del indice. No obstante, y como buena práctica cuando quieras que un parámetro de una función sea de sólo lectura, pásalo de forma constante, y te aseguras de que la función no puede modificarlo.

Más cosas....le pasas a la función muchos parámetros que pueden ser averiguados dentro de la misma, como es el número total de candidatos o la suma total de votos. Si haces esas averiguaciones dentro de la función, el código será más legible y la función más autónoma.

Te dejo una propuesta en esa línea:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_CANDIDATOS 4

void porcentajeVotos (const int votos[], float porcentajes[]);


int main()
{
    int votosPorCandidato[TOTAL_CANDIDATOS] = {1847,270,2433,83};
    float porcentajes[TOTAL_CANDIDATOS];
    porcentajeVotos(votosPorCandidato,porcentajes);
    for (int i=0;i<TOTAL_CANDIDATOS;i++)
    {
        printf("Candidato %d : Votos-> %d Porcentaje: %6.2f %\n",i+1,votosPorCandidato[i],porcentajes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void porcentajeVotos (const int votos[], float porcentajes[])
{
    int total_votos = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<TOTAL_CANDIDATOS;i++)
    {
        total_votos += votos[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<TOTAL_CANDIDATOS;i++)
    {
        porcentajes[i] = (float)(votos[i] * 100) / (float)total_votos;
    }
}
```

Comment: La etiqueta de la pregunta es C y no C++.

Comment: ¡Es verdad! Ya me vale. Voy a modificar la respuesta